# Robot.txt noindex

Tags: robots.txt, noindex

I have 2 web sites. First one is "test-www.xxxxxxx.net" and another one is "www.xxxxx.net". I want to make a dynamic no-index meta tag. Google robots can index my live site but I dont want it for my test site. Normaly I may add an attribute and make it dynamic in _Layout.cshtml as below.

```
@if (!Helper.IsLiveSite())
    {
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
    }
```

Is there a way that I can make it in robot.txt file ? It is written in some articles that "**I strongly recommend you use Noindex instead, whenever possible.**"

So please help! How can I do it in robot.txt. I dont know if the below file will create an error or not.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /styles/
Sitemap: http://xxxxxx/sitemap/sitemap.xml
Noindex: test-www.xxxxxxx.net/*
Noindex: http://test-www.xxxxxxx.net/*
Noindex: https://test-www.xxxxxxx.net/*
```

Thanks.

Comment: Google has a robots.txt tester tool: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/robots-testing-tool, but basically it's easiest to make a robots.txt file for each of your sites and not one combined for both. Then make the one for your test site `noindex` everything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can’t disallow *indexing* with robots.txt¹, only *crawling* (with `Disallow`).

If you want to disallow crawling of all documents from your test site, you have to upload a robots.txt that is accessible from `test-www.xxxxxxx.net/robots.txt`:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

(And this robots.txt file should *not* also be accessible from your live site.)

Search engines (those that support robots.txt) won’t visit (*crawl*) URLs on this host anymore. If they find URLs to documents on this host somehow (e.g., if another page links to them), they may list (*index*) them.

¹ Google supported (maybe still supports) this [experimentally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45866182/1591669), though.

Comment: Thanks for your help @unor

Comment: @unor I have followed your answer. But google still shows my site in search result. I have also put meta tags in my base.html.twig (I am Using symfony2.3). And It shows those metas in source. But Google still shows it in search result. Is there anything I am missing out???

Comment: @AshishShah: How long did you wait after adding this robots.txt? -- Do the results from your site show a description, or does it say that a description can’t be displayed?

Comment: @unor: It has been 2 days after addmin robots.txt. Yes, result shows description.

Comment: @AshishShah: You have to wait until the Googlebot visits your site again, which can take way longer than a few days.

Comment: @unor: ok... actually I tested my robots.txt in robits.txt checker provided by google, it has accepted my changes. Still I will wait few days to see what happens.