# Allow Google to Index ONLY the pages I want

Tags: user-agent, robots.txt, noindex

I have a large site (40,000+ pages) and want to minimise the level of pages that Google is Indexing, i.e. I wish to index only 500 pages.

I can only seem to find the option of *Noindex'ing* pages and for me to Noindex 39,500 pages wouldn't make sense.

An example of my Robots.txt file.

```
User-agent: *
Noindex:  /category/long-site-url-1/
Noindex:  /
Noindex:  /site-url-2/
Noindex:  /site-url-3/

Sitemap: https://sitedomain/sitemap.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

`Noindex` in robots.txt is/was [only an experimental feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45866182/1591669) (and never documented/specified).

You should add the `meta`-`robots` element in HTML or send the `X-Robots-Tag` header in HTTP for each affected page:

```html
<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
```

```
X-Robots-Tag: noindex
```